# regex to match only one capital letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match characters but I need to only match single capital letters.
For example:

```
'Hello World' - 2 matches
'Hello WOrld' - 1 match
'HEllo WOrld' - 0 matches
```

So far I have `/(?![A-Z]{1})/g` but I think I've misinterpreted what a negative lookahead is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookarounds in your regex:

```
/(?<![A-Z])[A-Z](?![A-Z])/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q0Srck/1)

- `(?<![A-Z])` - Negative lookbehind, asserts if previous character is not an uppercase English letter
- `(?![A-Z])` - Negative lookahead, asserts if next character is not an uppercase English letter

---

**EDIT:** Since Javascript doesn't support lookbehind, you can use this regex:

```
(?:^|[^A-Z])[A-Z](?![A-Z])
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/q0Srck/2)

Comment: thanks that's exactly what I need, however I'm using this in Javascript, how could I convert this?

Comment: only problem now is that it's matching the space before the capital letter when it's there, it says capture group 0 but that doesn't seem to exist?

Comment: Due to absence of lookbehind we will need to use a non-capturing group i.e. `(?:^|[^A-Z])`. That will match line start or anything that is not a capital letter.

Comment: are you saying it isn't possible?

Comment: No, I didn't say that :) What I am saying is that non-capturing group is not a zero width assertion like a lookahead or lookbehind.

Comment: okay I'm stumped, I found this article which deals with the problem we're having, but it appears I need to work on my RegEx Foo: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Comment: That article is doing exactly what I answered here. That you capture and discard lookbehind part in a non-capturing group.

Comment: yeah I'm not sure what that means, do I need to do this as two regexes?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by using Edge.js to call a c# function from Node, this allowed me to get around the restrictions with Javascript regex.

The final code ended up looking like this:

```
const getPerson = edge.func(function () {/*
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 public class RegexReplacer {
    public string PutSpacesBeforeCaps (string input) {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"((?<![0-9])(?<![A-Z])[A-Z](?![A-Z])(?![0-9]))");
        return regex.Replace(input, " $1");
    }
 }

 public class Startup {
    public async Task<object> Invoke(dynamic input) {
        RegexReplacer replacer = new RegexReplacer();
        return replacer.PutSpacesBeforeCaps(input.ToString());
    }
 }
 */});
```